# Trigger data-toggle=offcanvas event

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a great bootstrap 3 layout that use an "offcanvas" sidebar. All is working great on all screen size.

The HTML tag that triggered the sidebar is :

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-btn sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
```

How could i trigger this event with jquery ?? Sometimes i need to toggle the sidebar on user event, somtimes i need to display the page with the sidebar hidden.

I try to trigger the click event with jquery but it does nothing as there isn't any onClick event on this  tag...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found another solution using css only.

I closely inspect the dom change when the toggle button is hit and i replicate those changes when i need to toggle the sidebar.

I'm sure there's a jscript method to call but after several hours searching the web, the css solution is fine...

Comment: i guess it will depend on your specific html / css layout. My understanding is that the final result of the data-toggle action is only some css classes applied to some dom element, with animation. I'm using php and my goal was to sometimes display the page directly as if the user had toggled the element so the lack of animation of my pure css solution wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `collapse()` method that comes with Bootstrap. Something like

```
$('.sidebar-toggle').collapse();
```

should work.

See the link below for more info on `collapse()`:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage

Comment: Thx for your answer. However, it doesn't work. I try to call the .collapse() method on both the tag that toggle and the element that is shown / hidden. No error thrown, it does not work. In the doc you link to, they talk about element that use data-toggle="collapse", i use data-toggle="offcanvas", i don't know if it's the reason it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

Classname: "sidebar-collapse" is responsible for collapsing the sidebar.
For example:
`<body id="bodyContainer" class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse">`
This is for collapsed sidebar.

```
<body id="bodyContainer" class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

This is for non-collapsed sidebar.

So, basically you have to write jquery function to remove/include class "sidebar-mini"

Answer (score 0):

Add the sidebar-collapse class to the body tag to get this layout.